# Perl regex causing compilation error

Tags: regex, perl

Very new to Perl and have a problem with date validation

I have the following sub running to check that user date input conforms to YYYY-MM-DD

```
sub validateDate {
    VALIDATE-DATE: {
        $date = <STDIN>;
        if ($date !~ 
             /^(19|20)\d\d([-  /.])(0[1-9]|1[012])\2(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/) {
            print " $userStart in incorrect format, should be yyyy-mm-dd\n"
            print " Would you like to re-enter a date press (Y or N)?\n";
            my $choice = <STDIN>;
            if ($choice =~ /[Yy]/) {
                redo VALIDATE_DATE;
            } else {
                exit;
            }
        }
        return $date;
    }
}
```

However , when I run it I get this error:

`Unmatched [ in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^(19|20)\d\d([ <-- HERE -  / at common_subs.pl line 60.
Compilation failed in require at add.pl line 7.`

Error says that there is an unmatched ' [ ' but this isn't the case. I assume its something wrong with the regexp itself ? I am calling the sub from a separate file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, escape `/`. `/` is used as delimiter for regular expression literal. `/` inside that literal should be escaped.

```
/^(19|20)\d\d([-  \/.])(0[1-9]|1[012])\2(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/
#                 ^^
```

or use different delimiter:

```
m{^(19|20)\d\d([- /.])(0[1-9]|1[012])\2(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$}
```

---

The following line is missing terminating `;`:

```
print " $userStart in incorrect format, should be yyyy-mm-dd\n";
#                                                              ^
```

Comment: It's a lot prettier to use a different delimiter, so you don't have to write `\/`. For example: `m{^(19|20)\d\d([-  /.])(0[1-9]|1[012])\2(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$}`

Comment: @friedo, Thank you for comment. I updated the answer according to you.

Answer (score 3):

In fact your regex indeed is missing a `]`.

Since `/` is the delimiter symbol, the perl compiler stops at the unescaped slash inside your regex, so that you regex effectively looks like this:

```
/^(19|20)\d\d([-  /
```

which obviously is missing the `]` ;-)

Either use a different delimiter symbol (often people use `!` or something similar) or simply escape the slash.

Comment: I couldnt see the forest for the trees :)